# Easiest way to set up a post-find transformation hook in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to Mongoose and have been given a project to extend. I quickly grasped the concept of pre and post hooks, but was wondering why there are no such hooks for `find`, but only for `save` and `delete`. What would be the easiest way to set up some transformations on the retrieved objects? Of course, I want to do this at the model level, and not do it every time I retrieve some objects.

I found this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-post-find and I think it will do the job well, but since I am quite new to MongoDB, I wanted to ask here, to be sure that I won't end up in performance problems.

Answer (score 15):

That's what the `'init'` hook is for; it's executed on each doc loaded by a `find` query.

```
schema.post('init', function (doc) {
    // Transform doc as needed here.  "this" is also the doc.
});
```

It's only briefly mentioned in the [middleware docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) for some reason.

Comment: [Mongoose version 4 does now have a hook for `find`](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-version-40-mongoose-nodejs-odm).  What is the difference between `init` and `find`, and when should I use `init` for hooks instead of `find`?

Comment: This doesn't seem to edit the document that's returned to the caller of the `find`. Can you provide an example where you edit the doc and the results are returned to the `find`?